# How dont plot zeros in mathplotlib with bar chart

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I couldn't make it work to not plot the zeros. Any recommendations? Thanks

```
statusMont = dfFinal[dfFinal.columns[0:1]]
valoresMont =  dfFinal[dfFinal.columns[1:]]

dados = []
for itens in valoresMont.itertuples(index=False, name = None):
        dados.append(itens) 
values = dados

dadosKeys = []
for itens in statusMont.itertuples(index=False, name = None):
        dadosKeys.append(itens[0]) 
keys = dadosKeys

dicts = {}
j = 0 
for i in keys:
        values = np.array(list(dados[j]))
        dicts[i] = values
        j+=1
print(dicts) 

width = 0.6  # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
bottom = np.zeros(len(list(dados[0])))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for status, dict in dicts.items():
        p = ax.bar(selecao, dict, width, label=status,  bottom=bottom)
        bottom += dict
        ax.bar_label(p, label_type='center')

ax.set_title('Orçamentos - Por Montadora')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
print(dicts) # {'APROVADO': array([3, 0]), 'DECLINADO': array([36,  1]), 'EM ANDAMENTO': array([41,  5]), 'ENVIADO': array([65,  9]), 'RETRABALHO': array([0, 0])}
```

[Final Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEbZV.png)

Hi, i try some solutions with np.nan recommend here in stackoverflow, but i get the error: in _get_xy_transform
raise RuntimeError("Unknown return type")
RuntimeError: Unknown return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just filter out the coordinates where Y (the bar height) is zero. Rewriting the latter part of your code:

```py
for status, d in dicts.items():
    f = d != 0
    p = ax.bar(selecao[f], d[f], width, label=status,  bottom=bottom)
    bottom += d
    ax.bar_label(p, label_type='center')
```

I've changed `dict` to `d`, because `dict` is a reserved word and you may run into problems later if you need to use it. (You are eclipsing it, making it inaccessible as a feature.)

What this does is it creates a `numpy` Boolean array, `f`, based on a boolean condition (`d != 0`) which we can use to index into the `numpy` arrays `selecao` and `d` to select values (using Boolean indexing):

```
>>> x = np.arange(1,11)
>>> y = np.array([11,12,0,13,14,0,15,16,19,0])
>>> f = y != 0
>>> x[f]
array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9])
>>> y[f]
array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19])
>>> f
array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
       False])
```

For a deeper explanation, see https://numpy.org/doc/1.24/user/how-to-index.html

This can also be done less efficiently (this was my original answer) using list comprehensions, which may suit or help other people not using `numpy`:

```py
for status, d in dicts.items():
    f = [ (x,y) for x,y in zip(selecao, d) if y ]
    p = ax.bar([ x for x,_ in f ], [ y for _,y in f ], width, label=status,  bottom=bottom)
    bottom += d
    ax.bar_label(p, label_type='center')

ax.set_title('Orçamentos - Por Montadora')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

What this does is use `zip()` to reorganize the data and associate the X coordinates with the Y coordinates in tuples:

```
>>> x = np.arange(1,11)
>>> y = np.array([1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,9,0])
>>> x
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> list(zip(x,y))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (4, 3), (5, 4), (6, 0), (7, 5), (8, 6), (9, 9), (10, 0)]
```

(The `list()` is necessary because `zip()` returns an object suitable for iteration, not a list.)

We reorganize the data because we want to drop Xs where Ys are zero in addition to dropping the Ys. They have to dropped conjointly.

Then we use a list comprehension (`[]`s) with a condition/filter (`if y`) to filter out tuples (both X and Y) where Y is zero.

A list comprehension evaluates to a list of items that are iterated over (`for`), with an optional condition. So this means give me a list of tuples (`(x,y)`) for every tuple in the `zip()` object `zip(selecao, d)`.

I could have used `if y != 0` for clarity, but that's redundant, as a zero value evaluates as `False` in a boolean context.

```
>>> f=[ (x,y) for x,y in zip(x,y) if y ]
>>> f
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (7, 5), (8, 6), (9, 9)]
```

Then we break out X and Y separately again using two list comprehensions:

```
>>> [ x for x, _ in f ]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [ y for _, y in f ]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
```

This means that `f` is a list (iterator) of tuples, and iterate over them, ignoring (`_`) one or the other unused term, generating a list using the other term.

NOTE: This solution may not be suitable for large amounts of data because it restructures `numpy` data as lists, which is less efficient, but it looks like you are dealing with a small amount of data. I say this for others who may wish to implement this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I will try to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid plotting zero values in a bar chart using Matplotlib, you can filter out the zero values from your data before plotting. Here's an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
categories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
values = [0, 10, 20, 0, 30]

# Filter out zero values
non_zero_categories = []
non_zero_values = []
for cat, val in zip(categories, values):
    if val != 0:
        non_zero_categories.append(cat)
        non_zero_values.append(val)

# Plot the bar chart with non-zero values
plt.bar(non_zero_categories, non_zero_values)

# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel('Categories')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('Bar Chart without Zero Values')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

In the example above, the `categories` list represents the categories for the bar chart, and the `values` list represents the corresponding values. We iterate over the categories and values, filter out the zero values, and store the non-zero categories and values in separate lists.

Then, we plot the bar chart using `plt.bar(non_zero_categories, non_zero_values)` with the filtered non-zero values.

Finally, we add labels and a title to the chart using `plt.xlabel()`, `plt.ylabel()`, and `plt.title()`, respectively. The `plt.show()` function displays the chart.

By filtering out the zero values before plotting, the resulting bar chart will only display bars for the non-zero values, effectively excluding the zeros from the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I will try to implement.